# Are there any Shared Web Hosts that provide access to run Windows Services?

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I'd like to be able to have a very lightweight Windows Service call some code on the Web Server at regular intervals. Do I have any options besides a Dedicated/Semi-Dedicated Server?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any shared hosting company that would let you run a windows service - but shared hosts do let you run scheduled/reoccurring tasks.

Send the sales people of your top hosting choices an e-mail and ask them about reoccurring tasks (not windows services) and they will probably have something for you.

Back when I used http://webhost4life.com they had a way to add reoccurring tasks in their control panel - at a small extra cost, I never used it myself, I don't know how those tasks run and since I've left they replaced the entire hosting system (so I don't even know if this option still exists).

Answer (score 0):

[Fasthosts](http://www.fasthosts.co.uk/) in the UK do shared Windows hosting.

In fact, a quick check on Google brings back lots of results for shared windows hosting. try one of them.

Comment: Hi Piers - I need a host that would allow me to run Windows Services or run code at scheduled intervals, as per the question, not merely a Shared Windows Host.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for running a custom Windows Service is likely to be with a VPS solution.  There are plenty of quality VPS providers out there (Rackspace and Amazon to name a couple).  A shared web host is generally not going to allow custom Windows services to run due to security and performance issues.  If you find one that does, you will want to take a VERY close look at  their security policies and practices.